# Rails Filepicker, 3 buttons displaying instead of 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filepicker.io

Using Rails 4.2.4

I generated a scaffold in rails to test out filepicker.  Everything seems to be working well except when I hit refresh on the page that has the file picker button, 3 buttons display on the page instead of the original 1.  This happens on both Safari and Chrome.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

*When the page first loads, one button:*

[image: One Button]

*On refresh:*

[image]

application.html.erb source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>FilepickerTest</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

_form.html.erb source:

```
...
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :filepicker_url %><br>
  <%= f.filepicker_field :filepicker_url, :button_text => "Select Image", :button_class => "btn btn-default", :onchange => 'onImageUpload(event)' %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'Upload Image' %>
</div>
...
```

Comment: I see you are using turbolinks. Perhaps [this issue](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails/issues/52) is related.

Comment: Genius! Taking out the turbolinks fixes the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: @TommyJ please add an answer to your question and approve it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to turbolinks and was fixed by removing the javascript call in the application.html.erb file.